# Scale Polygons in javafx to their parent

Tags: java, javafx, scale, polygon, javafx-11

Suppose you have a polygon in a container and you want to scale it to the container when you create that container. You create width and height for that container and you have a defined polygon  already, housed in it. Now you want that polygon to always have the same width and height as the container it lives in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you solve it:

```
private void makePolyScale(int height, int width) {

    Scale scale = new Scale ();
    scale.setX(width/BASE_WIDTH);
    scale.setY(height/BASE_HEIGHT);

    scale.setPivotX(this.body.getBoundsInParent().getCenterX());
    scale.setPivotY(this.body.getBoundsInParent().getCenterY());

    body.getTransforms().addAll(scale);
}
```

Base width and baseheight are your polygons height and width. You can calculate that from your double array of points (just find minmax x/y and subtract the min from the max's of the respective x and y)

width and height are the width and height of your parent container.

Comment: I would recommend to clear the transforms first before adding the scale. This is required if your contianer size is frequently changing.

Comment: Thanks for reformatting this. I wrote this at 4am after wrangling with this for countless hours because I didnt know that you have to use scale.